# get reference table by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two table `user` and `course` where `user_id` is in table of `course` as foreign key.

How can I get referenced table from foreign key in php laravel framework. I mean is it possible ?

Any solution or other guide will be appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you can query the information_schema for this information:

```
SELECT `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` WHERE `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'your_database' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'course' AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'user_id';
```